# VS2015 slow debug of Asp.Net app after reinstall W10/VS2015.3

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I reinstalled my W10 machine and now debugging of an Asp.Net application is terribly slow. So I started Analyze | Performance Profiler to try to find out what is taking so much time.

While the analyzer is running, the app was lightning fast as was before the reinstall.

What changed with the reinstall ?
Moved from VS community to VS Enterprise.
Latest W10 release

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profiler tools was used in release mode, it was different from the normal VS debugging.

For the Debug performance issue:

(1)Disable intellitrace under TOOLS->Options->IntelliTrace.

(2)Disable the Microsoft Symbol Servers under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols.

(3) Clean up the temp folder.

(4) Delete the .suo file in your solution folder, and then re-open the project, clean and build it, debug it again.

Comment: Disabling intellitrace made a huge difference. Thx for the tip.